What model septic filter is this? What are compatible models?
This filter sits between second tank (semi solids) and third tank (effluent).

It inserts into that white flange that leads to effluent tank:

And here is a top picture with filter inserted in its place:

I could not find any brand or model numbers on filter itself. However, other septic system parts have Norweco branding all over it.
So far I have been able to find Norweco Model BK2000, but it looks slightly different.
I have also found this youtube video, but he does not mention exact model.

Normally these are just hosed clean and re-installed. Is yours broken in some way not obvious in the pictures?

@Ecnerwal plastic is brittle - handle broke off, only one of the 4 black lips are holding on. Also the picture does not show it very well, but the outside net is torn in many places.
